# C++ STL Set Erase by Value

Tags: c++, stl, set

I want to remove an element from `std::set`.

I am aware that the best and straightforward practice is to check its existence in the set using `set<T>::find(T val)` method, and then erase it using the returned `set<T>::iterator`. But I wish to use the shorthand method of erasing by value.

Even though `std::set` does provide that through the overloaded function `set<T>::erase(T val)` to erase by value as listed [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/), I couldn't find what happens if the value does not exist in the set.

As one would intuitively expect, does it *do nothing* if the argument value does not exist in the set? Is it guaranteed that it won't throw any error/exception?

Comment: From [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase): "Removes the element (***if one exists***) with the key equivalent to key." (emphasis mine) That kind of implies that nothing happens if the key corresponding to the value doesn't exist.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not a good reference site. It used to be worse, but it's still not good.

Comment: *"Is it guaranteed that it won't throw any error/exception?"* -- on cppreference it says "Any exceptions thrown by the Compare object."

Comment: Side note: `best and straightforward practice` – depends: If you stick with `std::set` anyway and don't care for number of occurrences, it doesn't really matter, erasing by value is just as fine. You'd rather have to be aware of the consequences if you change the container type or maybe create a template, e. g. std::vector doesn't provide erasing by value at all and in a std::multiset you'd erase all occurences by value whereas find/erase would only erase one element (which behaviour would you actually want???).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::set` abides by associative container requirements of [26.2.6 associative.reqmts](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.reqmts).

It returns the number of actual erased elements, which for `std::set` must be zero or one, dependent on existence. Per [26.2.6.1 associative.reqmts.except](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.reqmts.except), it is only guaranteed not to throw if the container comparator (which can be customized, obviously) does not throw when used during the search.

Answer (score 5):

From [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/)

> (1)   void erase (iterator position);
>
> (2)   size_type erase (const value_type& val);
>
> (3)   void erase (iterator first, iterator last);

**Return value**

For the value-based version (2), the function returns the number of elements erased.

Member type size_type is an unsigned integral type

---

So it returns 0 if no elements are erased.

Comment: Also further down, there is a Exception safety topic, describing a "no-throw guarantee"